# Simple approach for Adding object in a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, many-to-many

I have 2 classes `ConfigurationCollection` and  `OptionValues` which has a many to many relationship. I have tried solutions on the net to get it working. I tried adding another class to create two one to many relationship. But I am not understanding it the right way I suppose. And I also tried it without adding a third class.

Model classes

```
public class ConfigurationCollection
{
    public int ConfigurationCollectionID { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public int LsystemID { get; set; }

    public virtual Lsystem Lsystem { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
}
public class OptionValue
{
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }
    public string OptionVal { get; set; }
    public int OptionID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationCollection> ConfigurationCollections { get; set; }
    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
}
public class Config_OptionVal
{
    public int Config_OptionValID { get; set; }
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }
    public int ConfigurationCollectionID { get; set; }
    public bool OptionValChecked { get; set; }

    public virtual OptionValue OptionValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ConfigurationCollection ConfigurationCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create(int LsystemID)
 {
     var model = new ConfigurationCollection
     {
       LsystemID = LsystemID,
       Lsystem = db.Lsystem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LsystemID == LsystemID),
       OptionValues=new List<OptionValue>()
     };
     return View(model);
 }
```

I am not sure what should be written in the Controller. I am able to populate the `OptionValues` in my View. I am just missing something that could save the data into the database.

UPDATE : Create Post Action Method

```
public ActionResult Create(ConfigurationCollection con)
{
    foreach(var item in con.OptionValues)
    {
         if(item.OptionValueChecked)
            db.Config_OptionVal.Add(item);
    }
    db.ConfigurationCollection.Add(con);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Update : View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollectionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CollectionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

    <table class="table">
    <tr style="column-width:20px">
         <th>Option</th>
         <th>Option value</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Lsystem.Options)
    {
       <tr>
       <td><b>@item.OptionName</b></td>
       <td>                        
       @foreach (var ov in item.OptionValues)
       {                        
         <input type="checkbox"  id="OptionValues"/>@ov.OptionVal
       }
       </td>
       </tr>
     }
     </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: could you provide your current `Create` post action? So it will be easier to tell what you are missing

Comment: Updates question with the method. It doesn't execute in anyway because  i have no idea what needs to be written in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the third table is not mandatory.

```
public class ConfigurationCollection
{
    public int ConfigurationCollectionID { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
}
public class OptionValue
{
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }
    public string OptionVal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationCollection> ConfigurationCollections { get; set; }
}
```

The EF will recognize the n-m relationship.

In the Create method, you are sending a `ConfigurationCollection` object to the Controller, right? So, you just have to insert the object into the `DbSet`. Like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(ConfigurationCollection con)
{
    db.ConfigurationCollection.Add(con);
    //all of the OptionValues inside the 'con' object will be automatically inserted
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public ActionResult Create(ConfigurationCollection con, int[] optionsValuesIds)
{
    db.ConfigurationCollection.Add(con);
    foreach (optionValueId in optionsValuesIds) 
    {
       //if you are using the 'third class'
       Config_OptionVal cnfOpt = new Config_OptionVal();
       cnfOpt.ConfigurationCollection = con;
       cnfOpt.OptionValueID = optionValueId;
       db.Config_OptionVal.Add(cnfOpt);

       //if you are NOT using the 'third class' 
       OptionValue optVal = db.OptionValues.Find(optionsValuesIds);
       con.OptionValues.Add(optVal);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="OptionValuesIds" value="@ov.OptionValueID"  id="OptionValues"/>@ov.OptionVal
```

Models:

If you are using the 'third class', modify your classes as follows:

```
public class ConfigurationCollection
{
    //...
    //public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Config_OptionVal> OptionValues { get; set; }
}

public class OptionValue
{
   //...
   //public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationCollection> ConfigurationCollections { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Config_OptionVal> ConfigurationCollections { get; set; }

}
```

If you are not using the 'third class':

```
public class ConfigurationCollection
{
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
}
public class OptionValue
{
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationCollection> ConfigurationCollections { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: But how would be the id of `OptionValue` be stored in the database?

Comment: If the `OptionValue` is a new record, it will be automatically created (see the edit for auto-generated PKs). If it is an existing record, you have to load them from database, insert to the collection, and then add the `con` object to the `DbSet`. If the second option matches with your requirements, you can also use your third table and just send the PKs to EF, without loading the records.

Comment: I already have the OptionValues in my DB.. In my View I list out all the possible OptionValues that could be selected. I am wondering what would be my `ConfigurationCollection` look like?  It will have a row for its id and name. Where will the list of selected OptionValues be stored

Comment: Now i could understadn it better. But I a do not know how i could pass the array of `OptionvaluesID` to the controller

Comment: Updated my Question. I tried using `Html.CheckBoxFor()`, but i did not have any model to be bound to that value. The OptionValues are genereated based on the ID of the Lsystem that is being passed for the creation of the `ConfigurationColelction`

Comment: Take a look at the updated `View`. Now, every checked `OptionValue` will bind to the `OptionValuesIds` array in the controller. See the updated `Create` action method as well.

Comment: That was such a simple method to work on. thanks a lot. i really looked into many tutorials. But nothing I could comprehend. Thanks again.. :) :) :)